# VB.NET - Process HTML Code from Textbox in Web Browser Object

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

I have not posted on here in a while, but i have a question, how do i process HTML Code from a TextBox into a WebBrowser? like Process the HTML Code written in a TextBox (in real time, mostly), Not save it yet (if possible), and run it in the WebBrowser Object?
Thank You,
Charles

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WebBrowser.DocumentText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_DocumentText) property, that allows to *get or set the HTML contents of the page displayed in the WebBrowser control*.